# "template polymorphism" when calling function for templated parameter of base type, with derived type?

Tags: c++, templates

I've got a template class:

```
template <class T>
class TemplateClass
{
   //irrelevant what this class does
}
```

And two classes, one base and one class which derives from it:

```
class Base
{
    //does whatever
}

class Derived : public Base
{
}
```

Now I want to assemble a function which can deal with TemplateClass of templated type Base* as well as TemplateClass of templated type Derived* without having to implement the function separately for both types.

In code, this is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
void DoSomething(const TemplateClass<Base *> &tc)
{
   //do something
}
```

And somewhere else in the code:

```
TemplateClass<Base *> a;
TemplateClass<Derived *> b;

DoSomething(a); //Works
DoSomething(b); //Doesn't work, but I'd like it to work
```

Is there a way to implement this without having to manualy overload DoSomething for Derived* ?

Comment: It is important to know what `TemplateClass` is for. Maybe you could use the CRTP and simply let `TemplateClass` inherite from its parameter type.

Comment: TemplateClass is a QuadTree used for spatial partitioning of 2D space. the leafs of the tree can be of any type, which is why it's templated. The DoSomething() function is actually the Draw() function of my renderer class.

Comment: It helps to understand that `TemplateClass` is **not** a class. It's a template. Its instantiations are classes, though.

Comment: I actually never realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, C++ does not support template covariance, so you cannot do that automatically. As a workaround, you could do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething(const TemplateClass<T*>& tc) {
    // in C++03, use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT and boost::is_convertible
    static_assert(
        std::is_convertible<T*, Base*>::value,
        "Template argument must be convertible to Base*"
    );

    // ...
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/jaxIa).

Comment: Thank you, that's excellent! Is std::is_convertible a C++0x feature? MSVC already seems to have it implemented, and I was thinking that current compilers aren't supporting C++0x STL features yet. static_assert also works like a charm. Oh C++ I'm falling in love again :)

Comment: You don't really need it: `void DoSomething(const TemplateClass<T*>& tc, Base* checkT = static_cast<T*>(0))`. The disadvantage of checking with a `static_assert` is that you may have another overload that would work, but is now hidden by this asserting overload.

Comment: That's true, although static_assert will detect any wrong-doings at compile time, which is a pretty big advantage in my opinion. In case I need to add more overloads of the function I will probably use your solution. For now, though, static_assert looks a tiny bit prettier to me.

Comment: @MSalters that won't solve anything though. parameters that use default arguments are ignored by overload resolution. So your version would still "hide" the other workable function (haven't tried, so if I'm wrong, please complain).

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: It's SFINAE; the default `Base*` argument is initialized with a `T*` which will fail if `T` isn't (publicly) derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple to solve this if you are not opposed to a more general situation:

I would simply add a template parameter to your `DoSomething` function:

```
template<class T>
void DoSomething(const TemplateClass<T *> &tc)
{
}
```

Of course, this doesn't allow you to directly constrain the parameter `T` to being a subclass of `Base`. But it will allow you to not write several overloads of `DoSomething`.

#### Edit

If your `TemplateClass` was intended to wrap a value of type `T`, then there may be a way to constrain to parameter for `DoSomething`.

Suppose `TemplateClass` were declared something like

```
template<class T>
class TemplateClass
{

public:

    TemplateClass( T value )
    : Value(value)
    {
    }

    T Value;
};
```

Then `DoSomething` could be written as

```
template<class T>
void DoSomething( const TemplateClass<T *> &tc )
{
    Base * b = tc.Value;
}
```

Now, during compilation, the line `Base * b = tc.Value` will only compile if `T` is set to a subclass of `Base`. Otherwise, it will fail due to an invalid conversion.

Of course, this is a very simple example which may ignore some elements of good design. But the principle is there, and this is the only way I am currently aware of the produce such a constraint on a template parameter.