# Doubt with the template instantiation problem in the below snippet of a user defined class

Tags: c++, programming-languages

Couldn't find anything relevant in forums So ,Please help me with this code .I'm brushing up my c++ concepts and met with a strange error

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
class base
{
    int i ;
public:
    virtual void f(){cout<<"base" ; return ;};
};
class derived: public base
{
int j ;
public:
    void f() {cout<<"derived" ; return ;}
};
template<class T>
class test
{
public:
    test(T b) 
    {
        b.f(); cout<<endl<<" "<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
base b ;
derived d;
test<derived> t(b); // cannot instantiate user defined type without typename
}
```

The following code fails to compile with the following error :

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘test<derived>::test(base&)’
test.cpp:19: note: candidates are: test<T>::test(T) [with T = derived]
test.cpp:17: note:  test<derived>::test(const test<derived>&)
```

I can make wild guess and arrive at an answer at to why did this happen .If i instantiate  a new base class from the template , everything works just fine , but not this one .
Can somebody tell me a good source for template instantiations and what are the rules/semantics , what is happening behind the curtain ?
thanks

Comment: This exact question (pretty much) was asked earlier today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558633/template-polymorphism-when-calling-function-for-templated-parameter-of-base-typ/6558681#6558681)

Comment: @Ken Wayne: That's not the same question. That question used a template type that took the base class, which was then fed into another template. This one uses just the base and derived classes as the template arguments.

Comment: @Nicol: As far as the scenario goes, this is *exactly* the same: a function with a parameter of the form `Type<Base>` is being used as `Type<Derived>`. (I realize it's not the same question - but that's because this OP is asking for a semantic explanation, whereas the other did not. Other than that, everything's the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base` is not a complete `derived` type, so you'll have to provide a constructor inside your template that fills in the missing details.

```
template<class T> //original template
class test
{
  public:
    test(T b)
    {
      b.f();
      cout<<endl<<" "<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    }
};
```

When you create an instance of this template based on `derived`, the compiler translates it to a class, which essentially boils down to this

```
class derivedtest
{
  public:
    derivedtest(derived b)
    {
      b.f();
      cout<<endl<<" "<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    }
};
```

The default constructor is not generated any more. However, a default copy constructor is still created.

```
derivedtest::derivedtest(derived const&);
```

As you can see, there is no way to pass base (by reference or copy) into the class.

The solution is to provide a constructor inside your template that fills in the missing details:

```
template<class T>
class test
{
  public:
    test(base const& item)
     : base(item)
    {
    }


    test(T b)
    {
      b.f();
      cout<<endl<<" "<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    }
};
```

By the way, your `base` should most likely have a virtual destructor

and `test(T b)` should be `test(T const& b)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation .Pretty clear now .And I know I should always have a virtual destructor to work with the object slicing and stuff .

Comment: @richi_18007: You're welcome. Virtual destructor in `base` ensures that `derived::~derived()` is called when you delete a `base*` that is pointing to a `derived` object instance. Object slicing is different.

Answer (score 2):

Your test snippet effectively defines this:

```
test::test(derived&)
```

As the error says, you're trying to invoke this instead:

```
test::test(base&)
```

> If i instantiate a new base class from the template , everything works just fine.

Similarly, I'm sure, if you passed "d" instead of "b", everything would also work fine.

You should be able to reproduce the same scenario without templates: just defined a member function that takes "derived" as an argument, and see what happens :)